# How to get Month, Year and day values from picker?

Tags: codenameone, picker

In codenameone I have a picker p1 and I want to get the values of Month, Year and day separately from the date given by the user, this code

```
String m1=Integer.toString(p1.getDate().getMonth());
String d1=Integer.toString(p1.getDate().getDay());
String y1=Integer.toString(p1.getDate().getYear());
```

generates an error when running even if there is no compilation error.

Comment: What's the error that's generated? Is that error only on the device? Only on the simulator or both? Did you check if `getDate()` is null?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I did it

```
Date d = p1.getDate();
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTime(d);


                        String m1 = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
                        String y1 = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                        String d1 = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```